# Cordova iPhone-only app not showing icon on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ipad

I have this problem with my cordova iPhone-only app:
When installing it on iPad it doesn't show the proper home icon but shows the "missing icon" file.

The config.xml seems ok:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <splash height="480" src="res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    <splash height="960" src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1136" src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <icon height="180" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="120" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="40" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="57" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="res/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="29" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <icon height="72" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="167" src="res/icons/ios/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="50" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="1024" width="1024" src="res/icons/ios/icon-1024.png" />
    <icon height="20" width="20" src="res/icons/ios/icon-20.png" />
    <icon height="40" width="40" src="res/icons/ios/icon-20@2x.png" />
    <icon height="60" width="60" src="res/icons/ios/icon-20@3x.png" />
</platform>
```

even the AppIcon file seems right.

[image]

Installing it on iPhone of course is ok.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: +Zane did you ever get this situated?

Comment: no, this is the first time I have this problem. Even starting a new cordova project from scratch performs the same issue.